# gwt html to display XML but spaces not showing up

Tags: xml, gwt

Using GWT's HTML(new SafeHtmlBuilder() .appendEscapedLines(String).toSafeHtml()), where String is an XML file. But the spaces don't show up on the page. In the html, there are spaces present. How do I convert them so the html displays real spaces?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the XML file and the output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've just tested your example and I can see spaces. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Maybe try with [`PreElement`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/PreElement.html): `PreElement pre = Document.get().createPreElement(); pre.setInnerSafeHtml(...);`

Comment: @mrunion No, I can't. I'm on two different networks. One where I'm doing the development and this one.

Comment: @Adam I'm trying the PreElement option now ...

Comment: @Adam I can get the <pre> in my page, but now the XML is not displayed at all.  I can see the whole file there though, using Firefox's Inspector. Guess I'll just display the xml without the lines being indented in my output.

Comment: Finally got things to work. What I did was add <code><pre> before the XML, using SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscapedAllowEntites(xml), and </pre></code> afterwards. That allows the XML to be viewed in the original formatting with line returns and the indenting of the XML too,